# How to uninstall/remove Package Control from Sublime Text 3?

Tags: uninstall, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

Searching for `uninstall package control` on Google, only results showing how to install packages with Package Control, or remove them, but not removing `Package Control` itself.

How can I remove `Package Control` from Sublime-Text-3?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Removing `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Package Control.sublime-package` should do it.

(Thus just reversing the 'Manual installation' described in https://packagecontrol.io/installation)

UPDATE:
More complete instructions can be found at the official docs (thanks @BartaTamás): https://packagecontrol.io/docs/troubleshooting#Purging_Old_Versions

Comment: Thanks! This should work (I already succeeded to remove it). I don't know why I didn't think of looking at the manual installation section. However there is also a section called `Purging Old Versions` in the docs of Package Control. I'm not surprised I didn't find it earlier with this name :D This section states that the `Package Control` folder in the `Packages` folder also needs to be deleted. I asked this question because I suspected such generated content. Please include it in your answer.

Comment: Updated, thanks @BartaTamás for the suggestion. Funny, I don't have that second folder. Just some cache and settings files in Packages/User, I guess the former only got created in old versions.

Comment: I did two Package Control uninstallation, one at my workplace, one at home. At home I had the folder, here I didn't. But might be worth to mention here.

Comment: this answer is out of date, 404 error on the sublime text site to the link you posted

Comment: Updated answer to fix dead link to new url. Thanks @EricB.

Answer (score 27):

Press Ctrl+Shift+P (or Shift+⌘+P on a Mac) 
type 'Remove' 
All the packages that can be removed will be shown in the list below. 
Select one and this is it.

Comment: This will not work if Package manage is not up due to some other packages' problem

Answer (score 10):

## Sublime Text 3

Run Sublime Text.

---

Select **Preferences** → **Package Control**.

Or

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> shortcut for (**Win**, **Linux**) or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> for (**OS X**).

---

Select Remove Package. <kbd>Package Control: Remove Package</kbd>

---

Start typing **name of the package** you want to remove and **select** it from the list of installed packages.

---

Wait for the *uninstallation* to complete.

Answer (score 6):

0
down vote

Simple steps for remove any package from Sublime as phpfmt, Xdebug etc..

1- Go to Sublime menu-> Preference or press Ctrl+Shift+P .
2- Choose -> Remove package option, after you choosing it will display all   packge installed in your sublime, select one of them.
3. After selection it will remove, or for better you can restart your system.

Comment: Copy-pasting voting status in the beginning of an answer makes me just wonder from where you copied this. That aside (copying is perfectly ok if the content is relevant and good, although adding a link to the original would be nice), how does this answer differ from the one provided by Kaloyan Stamatov more than a year ago?

Comment: I don't know what the hell "0 down vote means" but this answer deserves down votes. It doesn't answer the question. This removes packages, the question is how to remove "Package Control" - very different things.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue, if you run OS X, is that you may have upgraded Xcode, and Apple has decided to not let you run `git` because you have not accepted the license agreement. This is if you are using the standard Apple-installed `git` (usually in `/usr/bin/git`).

Simply run `git` in the Terminal, and and press the space-bar and type `agree` to Apple's agreement to fix this. When `git` runs correctly, the Gitgutter will start working again.

Why `git` a program they had *nothing* to do with writing, needs to be covered by their mandatory (and ridiculously long) licensing agreement is beyond me, and is arguably in violation of the GPLv2 license of `git`. Another option is to just install your own `git`.